# How to solve Procedure or function add_route has too many arguments specified error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in ms sql server 2016 as follows

```
  create proc add_route
  (@from varchar(45),
   @to varchar(45),
   @cost decimal,
   @res int out)
   as
   begin
   if(not exists(select Route_id from Route_Master where From_location=@from and To_location=@to))
   begin
   insert into Route_Master(From_location,To_location,Cost) values(@from,@to,@cost);
   set @res=1;
   return @res
   end
   end
```

And I'm using the following code using c# to receive the output returned by the stored procedure.

```
   public int addnewroute(string from, string to, decimal cost)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("add_route", con);
            cd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from ",from);
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to",to);
            cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost",cost);
            cd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@res", SqlDbType.Int));
            cd.Parameters["@res"].Direction= ParameterDirection.Output;
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return (int)cd.Parameters["@res"].Value;
        }
     }
```

But I'm getting the error as ": Procedure or function add_route has too many arguments specified". But I'm passing equal number of arguments to the stored procedure. How do I clear this error?

Comment: Slight detour. You have defined @cost as a decimal but you did not specify the scale or precision. Do you know what the defaults are? You should always specify the scale and precision.

Comment: Do not `return @res` from stored procedure.